# To adjust a resultset based on another resultset in java

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, resultset

I have **four methods**, two methods namely **FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen() and ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User() gives beam_current values corresponding to entered logtime** through user.**Other two methods retrieve all other fields on these beam_current.**
I consider beam_current retrieved from FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen as reference beam_current and they are passed into another method namely refernece() method and other values corresponding to them are retrieved. Similar things are done with other two methods namely ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User and values of beam_current from it are passed into refarray_vac1.Now  I calculate the difference of values obtained from both of these methods and dispaly them through jsp apge.

Problem-
1)**I want that the all the values corresponding to  beam_current retrieved from refarray_vac1() method should come directly below to the corresponding values of refernece().**
**Output obtained till now is-**
[image]

Here you can see the rows displayed in light color are from refarray_vac1 and they are being compared with rows represented in gray color. Here value near 10 is represented below reference row of 10,but I want it tyo be represented below 20.02 row of the reference and null should be represented below gray color 10 row as in light color 10 value is missing.Then all the rows will come below its corresponding rows.

Code of methods is

```
public  LinkedHashMap<Double, String> FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(String name) throws SQLException {

    int row_id ;
    int bIdx = 0;
    //double[] vals = new double[47];
    double[] vals=null;
    //double[] bucket =new double[22];
    int rowIndex = 0 ;
    int i=0;
    String first=name.substring(1,19);
    String last =name.substring(24,42);
     try
        { 
          con = getConnection();
          stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
          String sql="select distinct beam_current from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where logtime between '"+first+"' and '"+last+"'"+
          "and (beam_current like '%9.95' or beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'  or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' or beam_current like '%_0.06')";

          System.out.println("Value of sql of FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen is"+sql);
          stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          rs = stmt.getResultSet();

         rs.last();
            int row_cnt=rs.getRow();
            System.out.println("row_count of closest " +row_cnt);
             vals = new double[row_cnt];
            rs.beforeFirst();
while(rs.next()) 
    {
   for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
         {
           vals[i]  = rs.getDouble(1);
         }
        i++;
     }
    }
 catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("\nException "+e);
    }
   //  get the max value, and its multiple of ten to get the number of buckets
     double max = java.lang.Double.MIN_VALUE;

     for (double v : vals) 
        {
        System.out.println("value of v after double v : vals"+v);
        max = Math.max(max, v);
        }
     Arrays.sort(vals);
     System.out.println("Min value in array in c "+vals[0]);
     double min=vals[0];
     int m2=(int) Math.round(min);
     int m3=(int) Math.round(max);

     int bucketCount = 1+((m3-m2)/10);
     double[] bucket =new double[bucketCount];

     //  initialise the buckets array to store the closest values
    double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bucketCount; i1++){
         // store the current smallest delta in the first element
         buckets[i1][0] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE; 
         // store the current "closest" index in the second element
         buckets[i1][1] = -1d;
         // store the current "closest" value in the third element
         buckets[i1][2] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
     }


     //  iterate the rows
     for (row_id=0 ; row_id < vals.length; row_id++) // row_id=137
     {
         //  get the value from the row
         double v = vals[row_id];

         //  get the closest multiple of ten to v
         double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v); // e.g. 50, 60, etc

         //  get the absolute distance of v from the multiple of ten
         double delta = Math.abs(mult - v); // 50 - 49.9 = 0.1
         //  get the bucket index based on the value of `mult`
        bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d) - m2/10;//50/10=5

      if (buckets[bIdx][0] > delta) // max>0.1
         {

           buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;//.01(50-49.95)
           buckets[bIdx][1] = row_id;
            buckets[bIdx][2] = v;


            System.out.println("beam_current: "+buckets[bIdx][2]);
            //z++;

         }
      } 

     System.out.format("    10x row value%n");
    for (int i1 =0; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)
    {
          bucket = buckets[i1];
         rowIndex = (int) bucket[1];
          int row_no=rowIndex+1;
          double rowValue = bucket[2];
          System.out.println("row index "+row_no+ "value is "+rowValue);
          DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 



          rs.absolute(rowIndex+1);
       map1.put(java.lang.Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(rs.getDouble(1))),"");

         }

    return map1;
    }
```

In both the methods FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen() and ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(),there is difference only in the size of resultset as logtime of both are different .Now I want size of ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User() resultset to be equal to resulset size of FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen, null should be placed wherever there is no corresponding value in the resulset of ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User whcich is obtained after processing .

code for ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User is-

```
public  LinkedHashMap<Double, String> ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(String start,String end) throws SQLException {

int row_id ;
int bIdx = 0;
double[] vals=null;
int rowIndex = 0 ;
int i=0;

try
        { 
          con = getConnection();
          stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

          String sql="select distinct beam_current from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where logtime between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"'"+
                  "and (beam_current like '%9.95' or beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'  or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' or beam_current like '%_0.06') ";

          System.out.println("Value of sql of FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen is"+sql);
          stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          rs = stmt.getResultSet();

         rs.last();
            int row_cnt=rs.getRow();
            System.out.println("row_count of closest " +row_cnt);
             vals = new double[row_cnt];
            rs.beforeFirst();
while(rs.next()) 
    {
   for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
         {
           vals[i]  = rs.getDouble(1);
         }
        i++;
     }
    }
 catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("\nException "+e);
    }
 //  get the max value, and its multiple of ten to get the number of buckets
 double max = java.lang.Double.MIN_VALUE;
 for (double v : vals) max = Math.max(max, v);
Arrays.sort(vals);
System.out.println("value at vals[0] c "+vals[0]);
double min=vals[0];
int m2=(int) Math.round(min);
int m3=(int) Math.round(max);


int bucketCount = 1+((m3-m2)/10);
double[] bucket =new double[bucketCount];



 System.out.println("bucketcount in closest "+bucketCount);

 //  initialise the buckets array to store the closest values
double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bucketCount; i1++){
     // store the current smallest delta in the first element
     buckets[i1][0] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
     // store the current "closest" index in the second element
     buckets[i1][1] = -1d;
     // store the current "closest" value in the third element
     buckets[i1][2] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
 }

 //  iterate the rows
 for (row_id=0 ; row_id < vals.length; row_id++)
 {
     //  get the value from the row
     double v = vals[row_id];
     System.out.println("value at "+row_id+": "+v);
     //  get the closest multiple of ten to v
     double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v);
     //  get the absolute distance of v from the multiple of ten
     double delta = Math.abs(mult - v);
     //  get the bucket index based on the value of `mult`
     bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d) - m2/10;


    if (buckets[bIdx][0]  > delta)
     {
      //  this is closer than the last known "smallest delta"
       buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;
       buckets[bIdx][1] = row_id;
       buckets[bIdx][2] = v;

       System.out.println("beam_current closeset: "+buckets[bIdx][2]);

     }
  }  
//   print out the result
for (int i1 =0; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)
{
      bucket = buckets[i1];
     rowIndex = (int) bucket[1];
 double rowValue = bucket[2];
      //System.out.println("row index "+row_no+ "value is "+rowValue);
      DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
      System.out.println("row index closeset "+rowIndex+ "value is closest "+rowValue);
   //System.out.println("value of rowIndex+1 is"+row_no);
      rs.absolute(rowIndex+1);
      user_current_map.put(java.lang.Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(rs.getDouble(1))),"");
     // map1.put(rs.getString(2),(rs.getString(1)));
      //l.add(map1);
     }
System.out.println("user_current_map "+user_current_map);

return user_current_map;
}
```

code for refarray_vac1() is

```
public  List<Vacc1_Decline> refarray_vac1(String fdate,String ldate) throws SQLException, ParseException {

        st_jsp.clear();
    //System.out.println("date from jsp is : "+date);
     List<Double> slist_user = new ArrayList<Double>(user_current_map.keySet());
      String s_user = StringUtils.join(slist_user, ',');
System.out.println("comma separated string by user_selection" +s_user);
    //  int i=0;
       try
            {  
              con = getConnection();
              stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);



                     String vs1= " sql query";

        //      System.out.println("value from user_selection is " +vs1);
              stmt.executeQuery(vs1);
               rs = stmt.getResultSet();

               while (rs.next()) {
                   Vacc1_Decline ref = new Vacc1_Decline();

                      ref.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));

                         ref.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));

                          ref.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));

                      ref.setSt1_vs1_bag1_rb(rs.getString(4));

                      ref.setSt1_vs1_bag2_rb(rs.getString(5));

                  st_jsp.add(ref);

                }

            }
       catch( Exception e )
                {
                    System.out.println("\nException in refarray_vac1 "+e);
                }


       return st_jsp;
      }
```

Comment: Use [jooq](http://www.jooq.org) and let your RDBMS do the work

Comment: I never used jooq, heard first time of it.Is there any other way?I have short time span.

Comment: @tid your question is unclear. Can you drastically simplify it? Eg by stripping out all code/SQL not absolutely essential to illustrate the problem? Like all those columns? Surely just one data column could show the problem. Or even just remove all references to SQL from the question, since it seems to reduce to a data sorting issue (regardless of the source of the data)

Comment: @Bohemian, I have removed the sql and columns which were not required.

Comment: @tid ok thx. You have shown current output - can you show desired output? Also, is this question essentially about merging two lists of row-like objects into one list, ordering them by beam_current?

Comment: @Bohemian,my desired output is that,the row below gray should come below its correspoding beam_current,i.e 19.96 should not come below 10, it should come below 20.02  and 0 should be filled in the row below 10 as there is no row corresponding to beam_current 10.There is no merging  of lists

Comment: @tid I have no idea what you are asking. What is it about the value 19.96 means it should come *after* 20.02?

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm saying that 19.96 beam_current row should come below beam_current 20.02 row, then the row below 20.02 i.e the row with beam_current 30.04 should come below the row with beam_current 30.01 and so on .As there is no row corresponding to beam_current 10,so 0 should be inserted in the row below 10 at all the columns.From ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User() method i'm getting the beam_current which should come below the rows of gray color and from refarray_vac1() method, all the columns of below row are retrieved.I hope this information may  have helped you in understanding my problem.