# whenever resultset is null, return a empty row in java

Tags: java, resultset

I have a java code,through which I process my sql query in such a way that I get only those values corresponding to  column  beam_current which are very near or equal to multiples of ten i.e whenever beam current is 10 or 10.02 ,20,30 or near by it,then the whole row corresponding to that current will be retrieved.

Now I want that whenever there in no such row exist in the resultset which is near by to multiple of 10,then null or empty row should be added in the table.

I have a date-picker,User selects date and time from it,I want that whenever there is no corresponding row in the selected date and time,then an empty row should be added in the table.

For all explanation and code please refer the link
**[To adjust a resultset based on another resultset in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299729/to-adjust-a-resultset-based-on-another-resultset-in-java)**

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question.  It is OK to refer to another SO post but your question should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Just a word of warning, you are opening yourself up for SQL Injection, (based on the linked source provided). I just want to understand you have all the data in one table ?

Comment: I have used multiple tables to retrieve the data and moreover the database is of a organization,where no one will do any harm to database.

Comment: @EJP, that question do not have an answer